# How to make os.remove not close my program after it fails to delete a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's the code

```
    import os
    while True:
        print "Upisite ime datoteke koju zelite izbrisati"
        izbrisi = os.remove(raw_input(""))
```

So I run this program in attempt to delete file but that file that doesn't exist so it just closes the program even its in while loop(when file does exist loop continiues).
I tried with if statement but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @ TigerhawkT3 I could not find that question/thread. I was trying with google for 20 min but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try:

```
import os
while True:
    print "Upisite ime datoteke koju zelite izbrisati"
    try:
        fname = raw_input("")
        izbrisi = os.remove(fname)
    except OSError as err:
        print "failed to remove %s" % fname
        pass #ignore the exception
```

Comment: It worked, thanks man. Where could I add my print "There's no such file" statement ?

Comment: @Cager before the pass statement...

Comment: Nevermind I figured out my self.